# getCurrentItem not returning the Current Item in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm making an applicaction with ViewPager (It has 3 pages), and right now I'm trying to make the first page to access the SQL Database and to print it data in a ListView (This functionality is just for the first page, the other pages have other functionalities not implemented yet), but now my problem is that the data is printed in the wrong page (Second Page). I'm using the method `getCurrentItem()` to know in which page I am. The code in the method `onCreateView` is as follows:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prioridad_alta, container, false);

List<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

ViewPager pg = (ViewPager) container;
int current = pg.getCurrentItem();

if (current == 0) {
    // Database access, I'm using a Cursor for the DB and adding 
    // the data to an arrayList to print it using the ArrayAdapter,
    // I don´t know if this is the most properly way of doing it
    // but currently my main purpose is making this works
}

ArrayAdapter adapt = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_prioridad_alta, R.id.textTarea, array);
ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setAdapter(adapt);

return rootView;
```

Just to be clear, the first time that I run the application the data is printed in the first page (but just the first time), after that when I change of page the data is printed only in the second page and never again in the first.

Next, I add the code of the changeListener for the pages which is implemented in the onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_prioridad_alta);

final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Prioridad Alta");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch(position){
            // Camnbia la pagina de prioridad
            case 0: toolbar.setTitle("Prioridad Alta"); break;
            case 1: toolbar.setTitle("Prioridad Media"); break;
            case 2: toolbar.setTitle("Prioridad Baja"); break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

This is the code for the PagerAdapter:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Prioridad Alta";
            case 1:
                return "Prioridad Media";
            case 2:
                return "Prioridad Baja";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: is the titles seted correctly? when you scroll?

Comment: Yes, titles work perfect

Comment: can you post the adapter for the pager

Comment: Edited, now it is in the botom of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are passing the position to the fragment check the position you are passing to the fragment instead of the pager selection index since the fragment are initialised before they are selected when on page 0 page 1 is also initialised.

so instead of

```
int current = pg.getCurrentItem();
```

use the position you send to fragment upon creation Fragment in newInstance(position +1)

```
int current =position -1;
```

Comment: I have implemented this code `ViewPager pg = (ViewPager) container;
            SectionsPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = (SectionsPagerAdapter) pg.getAdapter();
            int current = mPagerAdapter.getPosition() - 1;` but I'm experiencing exactly the same problem

Comment: I have added in the PagerAdapter a private variable (`private int pos`) for the position and the method `public int getPosition(){return pos;}`

Comment: not mPagerAdapter.getPosition() just the position you send in PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1); don't access the pager at all

Comment: great I had a lot of trouble with view pager before when you understands that it intialize multiple pages at the same time this help you fix some of the strange issue it causes

Answer (score 0):

use

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {       
        conterchange.setText(""+(1+position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Comment: The Listener is implemented in the onCreate method, I added it, thanks for reminding it to me, just a question about the code in the onPageScrolled what makes the line `conterchange.setText(""+(1+position));`?